# ios-focusing make too long

Tags: ios, zbar

I realize scanning bar code with `ios` abd `zbar`:`ZBarReaderViewController`.but when the camera show, the focusing very blurry,always need two second focus to become clear,why this happen?is there some setting that can make it better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can play around with flash/torch settings to enable better focusing. Bad/Low light is a big enemy of auto-focus.  Setting focus setting to continuous will help with scanning.

Keep in mind the minimum focus distance of the camera, at a certain point it won't focus.